# SAS gmap and label centering

Tags: sas

I have a Problem where I could not find an easy solution and I am looking for some ideas or tipps.

I am working with SAS on a project which result should be a map of europe, where the countries get colored after a certain algorithm. I use the maps.europe data and the %annomac and %maplabel macros to label the countries.

This works pretty fine, except for Portugal and Spain - because theese countries have island far away from the coastside, the calculated centroid from %maplabel of the country is not in the center of the country: [image: Portugal is in the sea]

Unfortunately I just can cut portugal completely out of the map but not the Islands

I have tried already this method:

- Try to cut the parts of the map via gproject which contains the islands - this delievered unexplaniable results to me (just showing some parts of europe, even if I set the parameters extremly wide)

and now I am a bit stuck.

I already thought about this ideas:

Comnbining the map.europe with the map.spain and and map.portugal where I delete the islands before, but I am not sure how to do that that the labeling and all still works for theese combined data.

Is it possible to set the label points for portugal and spain manually and overwrite the data from the %maplabel macro?

Or is there an even easier solution?

Thanks for your help and best regards
stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with those macros, but given how GMAP works, I would indeed override the annotate dataset.  You may want to read up on how annotate datasets work, but in general:

The GMAP statement will have an option, `annotate=` and some dataset.  Find that dataset, let's say it's called ANNODS.

Then look at that dataset.  Identify a row that has `function=text` and `label=PORTUGAL`.  That is the row you need to modify the x/y coordinates of in order to move the label around (`x1` and `y1`).  You might need to play around with this some to get the right coordinates.

Then run the PROC GMAP, and you should have a newly moved-over Portugal.

Comment: Hello Joe, you are right - this was the simplest solution, although I do not like theese kind of manual corrections. Thanks for the explaning of the anno dataset - it worked as you explained.

Comment: It's probable that you could change the macro to work better (ie, to disregard disparate points), but I don't know anything about how the macros calculate the centroids.